Difference between accuracy during training and accuracy during testing
In the model below the accuracy reported at the end of the final validation stage is 0.46, but when reported during the manual testing the value is 0.53. What can account for this discrepancy?
import torch
from torch import nn
import torchvision.models as models
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryAccuracy
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import NeptuneLogger
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
from os import environ

class ResNet(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, n_classes=1, n_channels=3, lr=1e-3):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.validation_accuracy = BinaryAccuracy()
        
        backbone = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
        n_filters = backbone.fc.in_features
        if n_channels != 3:
            backbone.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(n_channels, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
        layers = list(backbone.children())[:-1]
        self.feature_extractor = nn.Sequential(*layers)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(n_filters, n_classes)
        self.loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

    def forward(self, x):
        features = self.feature_extractor(x)
        logits = self.classifier(features.squeeze())
        return logits

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.hparams.lr)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = self.loss_fn(y_hat, y)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = self.loss_fn(y_hat, y)
        self.validation_accuracy.update(y_hat, y)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        return loss

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        val_acc = self.validation_accuracy.compute()
        self.log('val_acc', val_acc, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        self.validation_accuracy.reset()

    def predict_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        preds = torch.sigmoid(y_hat) > 0.5
        return preds, y

def get_dataloader():
    # Create a simple synthetic dataset for demonstration purposes
    x = torch.randn(100, 3, 224, 224)
    y = torch.randint(0, 2, (100, 1)).float()
    dataset = TensorDataset(x, y)
    return DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=8)

# Set up model, data, and trainer
model = ResNet()
train_loader = get_dataloader()
val_loader = get_dataloader()

logger = NeptuneLogger(
        api_key=environ.get("NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN"),
        project="richbai90/ResnetTest",
        tags=["MRE", "resnet"],
    )


trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=3, logger=logger, log_every_n_steps=1)

# Train and validate the model
trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)

# Predict on validation data
val_loader = get_dataloader()
preds, targets = [], []
for batch in val_loader:
    batch_preds, batch_targets = model.predict_step(batch, 0)
    preds.extend(batch_preds)
    targets.extend(batch_targets)

# Calculate accuracy manually for comparison
preds = torch.stack(preds).view(-1)
targets = torch.stack(targets).view(-1)
manual_accuracy = (preds == targets).float().mean().item()
print(f"Manual accuracy: {manual_accuracy:.4f}")


You are generating an entirely different random dataset for the manual validation data.
The first time you generate a validation set is in the lines
# Set up model, data, and trainer
model = ResNet()
train_loader = get_dataloader()
val_loader = get_dataloader()

And the second time you generate a validation set is the lines
# Predict on validation data
val_loader = get_dataloader()

Since the get_dataloader() function generates a random synthetic dataset each time you run it, you are essentially running the same accuracy tests on two different sets of data.
To fix this, I would remove the second initialization of val_loader, so that the same Dataloader instance is used in the manual and automatic tests.
